# Global declaration of variable in android

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

I am new to android development, I am parsing a xml file through SAX parser and storing the parsed data into a string.Now i need to use that string in another class, so i need to know how to call that parser in the new class.
 thanks in advance

Comment: Note that global data is a bad idea unless it's constant.

Comment: Without knowing your class hierarchy in more detail, I'm wondering what's preventing you from using basic getter method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always make a class that contains all of my globals and call it "Constants.java"

```
final public class Constants//final to prevent instantiation
{
    public static final String SOME_STRING = "0.04";
    public static final int SOME_NUMBER = 5;
    public static final float METERS_PER_MILE = 1609.344f;

    //private constructor to prevent instantiation/inheritance
    private Constants()
    {
    }
}
```

to use one of these in your code, be sure to import the class and use:

Constants.SOME_NUMBER

Comment: Why don't you use an interface instead?

Comment: because "an interface is a group of related methods with empty bodies"

Comment: eventhough "an interface definition may also define properties that are automatically public static final", I consider the main purpose of an interface to represent a contract of related methods with empty bodies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static variable and can access it any where in the application

```
public static int myVar = 1;
```

access it by ClassName.myVar

Answer (score 2):

You can use intent to pass the value.
Also,you can use the manifest.xml to make a gloable variable.

Answer (score 1):

Using the android application extension is NOT multi-process safe, as described here:
[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)
Note the first response. He defines how to extend the application itself but makes a note that 
"this method offers no way easy way of persisting the global state. If your application finds this necessary you should be using some sort of store; see the Android docs for a variety of methods."
I have also seen other posts that state that between processes this method needs to be modified slightly, but I think it's possible.
Let me know if I understood that wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You should use application object to get a global variable, you can see a working example here http://www.helloandroid.com/category/topics-covered/application-object

Application class documentation is stated here 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: I am not sure, but you can always use synchronized keyword.